# anomaly detection in credit card fraud with undercomplete or overcomplete autoencoder

Tags: autoencoder

Which type of autoencoder is best to detect anomalies? should I use an undercomplete or overcomplete autoencoder for the detection of anomalies?

I have tried it already with an undercomplete autoencoder, but I'm just wondering if an overcomplete autoencoder would also be a good choice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.